# ASP.NET universal controller for database dictionaries (using Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, generics, reflection

I've got some models that only have two fields: Id and Name. All this models inherit from IDbDictionary interface.

My goal is to make "universal" controller for CRUD operations for this models. My problem is how to (using EF) modify database table by name. For example, there is method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(IDbDictionary newRecord, string collectionName)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.<collectionName>.Add(newRecord);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View("Success");
        }

        return View("Create", newRecord);
    }
```

Is there a way to do it the way I described? I thought about reflection, but I've no idea how to do this.

Regards,
C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would have a `Service` that would handle your generic database operations which you can call from all your methods. Example:

```
public class DataService
{
    public readonly ApplicationDbContext dbContext;

    public DataService(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public void Create<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : IDbDictionary 
    {
        this.dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        this.dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Then in your method you would use:

```
var dataService = new DataService(this.dbContext);
dataService.Create<ClassName>(newEntity);
```

Comment: It looks nice, but is there any way to pass string as `TEntity` with reflection or something?

Comment: @Calfy I don't know what you mean

Comment: My point is: instead of putting `ClassName` in `Create<ClassName>` method, use string with class name. But never mind, I think that my idea is unplayable. I think I just need to make seperate controller for each dictionary, but I will use your solution with data service. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Calfy You should replace ClassName with whatever class newEntity is.

Comment: Yup, I know this ;) But my point was that I have `string temp = "className"`, I do some magic with this and I can pass it as `ClassName` in `Create<ClassName>` :)

Comment: @Calfy Oh I understand now. Yes, unfortunately I don't think that's possible. I've looked around a bit and I couldn't find a solution